# Tensorflow : What is the solution for decreasing learning time in repetition of the same graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph, training-data

I wanted to find the best tensorflow graph by input the variable feature data into the graph. (ex. first time, train for 3-feature input data / 2nd time, train for 4-feature input data...and so on)

I made the following code, but the result is that the learning time continues to increase. I do not know what is the problem.(os : window)

ask(1) : Someone said to me "you should make [train_op = optimizer.minimize(cost)] outside of while loop ". But, the problem is I don't know why should do that? Whenever I create that graph, is the graph not initialized? Should I kill or reset some kind instance?

ask(2) : How can I change "input feature" or "graph" at every for loop iteration?

*** addition : There was an error in my code. so fix that.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time

def backporpa():
    feature = np.random.randint(3,8)  # range of feature
    x_data = np.random.rand(50,feature)
    y_data = np.random.rand(50, 1)
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    # change input data feature every for loop
    W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([feature, 30], -1., 1.))
    W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([30, 1], -1., 1.))
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([30]))
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
    L1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W1), b1)
    L1 = tf.nn.relu(L1)
    outputLayer = tf.add(tf.matmul(L1, W2), b2)
    outputLayer = tf.nn.relu(outputLayer)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(outputLayer - Y, 2))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(cost)
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for step in range(100):
        sess.run([train_op,cost],feed_dict={X:x_data, Y:y_data})

for n in range(10):
    aaa = time.time()
    backporpa()
    print("time : ", time.time() - aaa)nter code here
```

(result)

```
time :  0.24463677406311035   
time :  0.270143985748291    
time :  0.31017184257507324    
time :  0.3471488952636719    
time :  0.4152336120605469    
time :  0.4102210998535156    
time :  0.48073315620422363    
time :  0.5302832126617432    
time :  0.5165011882781982    
time :  0.6258664131164551
```

Comment: You are missing some fundamental concepts of Tensorflow. In Tensorflow you define a graph. So in this case its the full neural network. Then each time you want to use the graph you use sess.run to tell tensorflow to evaluate the graph with new inputs that are fed in via the feed_dict. In your code, every time you call backpropa(), you are creating new graph elements and then reinitializing all variables. Instead, Define the graph and call sess.run seperately. I would add a more comprehensive answer but since there  are tons of intro to tensorflow tutorials. I reccomend you check them out.

Comment: thank Matt.  There was an error in my code. so fix that.

Comment: thank Matt.  There was an error in my code. so fix that. 
I have 20 kinds of input data (3 feature data, 4 feature data...and so on) 
What i want is to find best graph  for every input data and save it by file. so i should change the graph every for loop iteration

Comment: It seems like you want a dynamic graph. Checkout pytorch for that. Otherwise you can make Tensorflow work but you need to be pretty good at it before you can design it for dynamically sized inputs.

Comment: As you told me, i searched pytorch... and.. that was what i want ! Thank Matt.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([3,30], -1.,1.))
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([30,1], -1.,1.))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([30]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
L1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(X,W1), b1)
L1 = tf.nn.relu(L1)
outputLayer = tf.add(tf.matmul(L1,W2), b2)
outputLayer = tf.nn.relu(outputLayer)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(outputLayer-Y,2))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(cost)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

outside of your loops, so in your case, outside of the function `backporpa`. Otherwise you are starting a new session and a new graph every iteration. This means at every iteration you are using up more and more memory (thus you are slower) and also you forget everything which you learned previously.

Comment: thank patapouf. There was an error in my code. so fix that. 
Is there any solution to change input feature dimension for the graph
or delete graph or kill instance ?

Comment: You should ask a new detailed question about that, as it is not possible to answer in a comment.

Comment: Also if the answer was what you were looking for, you should accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer.